# Java like interface for restricted access in Python

Tags: python

In java you can use interfaces to restrict access to class methods
ex:

```
public interface InterFace {
    public int method1();
}

public class Example implements InterFace{
    public int method1(){...}
    public int method2(){...}
}
```

which means that any method which takes an `InterFace` as input wouldn't be able to access `method2` (except with casting)

Is there a way to get this sort of behavior in python *(by for example encapsulation)*

In other words is there a pythonic way to restrict what methods can be used on an object when passed to another function

**PS**

```
class A:
    def j(self):
        return 7

    def l(self):
        return 5

class interfaceforA:
    def __init__(self,obj)
        self.obj = obj

    def l(self):
        self.obj.l()
```

I know you can use something like this, but this isn't practical for large amount of classes. So I'm looking for something more general.

Comment: If you want to pretend Python is statically typed, all the big work in that area is happening with type annotations and static analysis.

Comment: Also, your "PS" code doesn't seem substantially less practical than the Java. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: I have to agree with user2357112. You've answered your own question here. Throw an `_` in front of the instance field in the interface, and you've got the closest thing Python has to information hiding without serious hacking.

Comment: Got to say it, you're understanding of why to use interfaces seems to be flawed, so that makes the question a little odd.

Comment: "In other words is there a pythonic way to restrict what methods can be used on an object when passed to another function" no, there isn't.